# Сервер обновлений

Tags: клиент-сервер

Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть если мне надо организовать сервер обновлений? Есть лаунчер для игры и при необходимости он скачивает обновления. Сейчас это реализовано через ftp, но на сколько я понимаю это не есть хорошо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если объем обновлений небольшой (обновляется только сам лаунчер), то отдача новой версии по *http* или *ftp* не является чем-то плохим.

С другой стороны, если обновления включают в себя и игровой клиент размером до нескольких гигабайт, то стоит посмотреть в сторону *p2p*. Т.е. раздачу клиента организовать через torrent (не обязательно именно его) - это позволит избежать слишком больших нагрузок на сервер обновления при выходе новой версии клиента.

Для работы с torrent'ами можете использовать свободные библиотеки [***monotorrent***](http://www.monotorrent.com/)  или [***libtorrent***](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/).